# Very big data in mysql table. Even select statements take much time

Tags: mysql, database, performance, query-optimization, reporting

I am working on a database and its a pretty big one with 1.3 billion rows and around 35 columns. Here is what i get after checking the status of the table:

```
Name:Table Name
Engine:InnoDB
Version:10
Row_format:Compact
Rows:12853961
Avg_row_length:572
Data_length:7353663488
Max_data_length:0
Index_length:5877268480
Data_free:0
Auto_increment:12933138
Create_time:41271.0312615741
Update_time:NULL
Check_time:NULL
Collation:utf8_general_ci
Checksum:NULL
Create_options:
Comment:InnoDB free: 11489280 kB
```

The Problem I am facing that even a single select query takes too much time to process for example a query  `Select * from Table_Name limit 0,50000` takes around 2.48 minutes
Is that expected?

I have to make a report in which I have to use the whole historical data, that is whole 1.3 bil rows. I could do this batch by batch but then I would have to run queries which are  taking too much time many times again and again.

When the simple query is taking so much time I am not able to do any other complex query which needs joins and case statements.

Comment: can we take a look of your DB schema? run `DESC Table\ Name`

Comment: Add index in your Table, use Index Column in where clause.

Comment: Do not use * for selection, extract only the columns desired by you.

Comment: i am not sure about mysql configuration, but for having faster sql queries **run the explain plan** - see where all the cost and memory are. post it here and we will let you know how to make sql query faster

Comment: Try range partitioning on your table. won't affect your data. may improve your performance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common practice is, if you have huge amount of data, you ...

1. should not `SELECT *` : You should only select the columns you want
2. should Limit your fetch range to a smaller number: I bet you won't handle 50000 records at the same time. Try to fetch it batch by batch.

Comment: i have to make a report in which i have to use the whole historical data that is whole 1.3 bil rows. I can do this batch by batch but then i would have to apply queries on time which are again taking too much time add to that huge number of batches that i have to process. Really stuck here

Comment: Queries for reporting always spent a lot time. The real solution is, define a query that can fetch all useful data (no junk) from your data. **Add index if applicable**

Comment: `create table interm1 as select device_uuid,name from 
 Table name` a query like this is taking around 20-30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

A common problem many database administrators face. The solution: **Caching**.

Break the Queries into more simpler and small queries. Use **Memcached** or other caching techniques and tools Memcached saves key vaue pairs, check for a data in memcache..if available, use it. If not fetch it from database and then use and cach. Next tie the data will be available from cahe.

You will have to develop own logic and change some queries.  Memcached is available here:

http://memcached.org/

Many tutorials are available on the Web

Comment: i do not recommend memcached to "hide" bad designed (without proper indexes) tables. seems like to "hide the rubbish under the carpet"

Comment: no..databses are slow!! caching is fast..from facebook to twitter..all major sites use memcached.

Comment: i use memcached daily, but i use memcached once i have my queries fine-tuned, and if you want FRESH data (report data, real-time stats,etc) memcached is useless

Comment: The caching would be useless for a report application. **1.** he wont access same data frequently. **2.** caching is useful for web application to access frequently used data

Answer (score 1):

enable in your my.conf the slow queries up to N seconds, then execute some queries and watch this log, this gives you some clues and maybe you could add some **indexes** to this table.

or do some queries with EXPLAIN. http://hackmysql.com/case1

Comment: Query with 1.3 billion rows is probably taking over 1 second. So, slow query log will log all his report SQL statement.

Comment: believe it or not, i handle some tables with this amount of rows and the selects takes less than 1 sec :D

Answer (score 0):

A quick note that is usually an easy win ...

If you have any columns that are large text blobs, try selecting everything except for those fields.  I've seen varchar(max) fields absolutely kill query efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very wide average row size and 35 columns.  You could try vertically partitioning the table, that is, split the table up into smaller tables that are related to each other 1:1 with a subset of columns from the table.  InnoDB stores rows in pages and is not efficient for very wide rows.

If the data is append-only consider looking at ICE.

You might also look at TokuDB because it supports good compression.

You can consider using partitioning and Shard-Query (http://code.google.com/p/shard-query) to access data in parallel.  You can also split data over more than one server for parallelism using Shard-Query.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding WHERE clause: **WHERE 1=1**
If it doesn't give any effect then you should change your engine type to **MyISAM**.

Comment: seems not related . By the way, changing DB Engine with such amount of data takes a long time.

Comment: i cant change my database. I believe that mySql must have some sort of solution for big tables

Comment: MyISAM is faster in reading than InnoDB. I think it's better if you test it with tables which have lots of rows, and then give a right opinion.

Comment: In past I have faced a similar problem. Adding WHERE 1=1 improves time execution, but changing it's engine type to MyISAM it improves more.

Comment: Where 1=1 is true for all conditions, and will have a similar execution plan as without Where. Try with EXPLAIN you'll see.

Comment: For a text based search MyISM is better than INNODB.